# How to add json to resolve array in Angular 9

Tags: angular, webpack

I am building angular 9 application and I want to have something like that:

```
  module.exports = {
    // ...
    resolve: {
      modules: ['src', 'node_modules'],
      extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.json']
    }
    // ...
  };
```

I mean I want to add resolve extentions.
I know I should modify webpack config, but there is no webpack file to modify

Comment: If you can provide more details about what you're trying to achieve, people can help you better.

Comment: According to the webpack documentation. What you are doing is completely correct: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveextensions. So what are you trying to achieve here that doesn't seem to work?

Comment: yes that's correct if I have webpack configuration file, but in angular 9 I have no webpack.config file, it's hidden from developer, instead I have angular.json